# How to remove Single Spaces from String VBA (Without removing consecutive spaces)

Tags: string, vba

I'm writing code in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to take a string and remove all occurrences of single spaces, while leaving consecutive spaces in tact.

This is what I have now, but it is just removing all spaces and replacing them with the dash.

Thanks for any help or guidance!

```
Sub Main
    'Nothing happens when the code executes the following string
    CombineText("Job           Hours        Pay   Labor %")

    'When the following executes it should look like this
    'Major-Group-Total     382       2,085.25
    CombineText("Major Group Total     382       2,085.25")
End Sub

Sub CombineText(searchString As String)   
    a = Len(searchString)

     For n = 1 To a    
        If Mid(searchString, n, 1) = Chr(32) Then
             searchString = Application.Substitute(searchString, Mid(searchString, n, 1), "-")
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Check if the current character is a space.  If it is, check the character to the right and to the left.  If neither of those are a space, replace it with a -, if either is a space, do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Function CombineText(sSearch As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sReturn As String

    sReturn = sSearch

    For i = 2 To Len(sReturn) - 1
        If Mid$(sSearch, i, 1) = Space(1) And Mid$(sSearch, i - 1, 1) <> Space(1) And Mid$(sSearch, i + 1, 1) <> Space(1) Then
             Mid$(sReturn, i, 1) = "-"
        End If
    Next i

    CombineText = sReturn

End Function

?combinetext("Major Group Total     382       2,085.25")
Major-Group-Total     382       2,085.25
?combinetext("Job           Hours        Pay   Labor %")
Job           Hours        Pay   Labor-%
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for! I was getting this pretty close with the comment @nhgrif had made, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with all the VBA syntax and you beat me to it. Well done

Comment: I did not realize MID() was more than just a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `RegExp` to do this in a single shot rather than loop through the characters

```
Function CleanStr(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "(\S)\s(?=\S)"
.Global = True
CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, "$1-")
End With
End Function

Sub Test()
Debug.Print CleanStr("Job           Hours        Pay   Labor %")
Debug.Print CleanStr("Major Group Total     382       2,085.25")
End Sub
```